# Error with Thousand Separator in Jinja2 on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, youtube-api, jinja2

I'm working on YouTube Data API. I'm trying to display the viewCount from the video statistics in my HTML using jinja2 on Google App Engine.

When I specify constant values like in my template like:

```
{{ '{0:,}'.format(1234567890) }}
```

the output works okay as:

```
 1,234,567,890
```

However, if I specify the code as:

```
 {{ '{0:,}'.format(video_item.statistics.viewCount) }}
```

It does not work and displays internal server error saying:

```
{{ '{0:,}'.format(vivi.statistics.viewCount) }}, ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'.
```

I'm not sure what that means.

However,

```
{{video_item.statistics.viewCount}}
```

works correctly. Can someone help me out please? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@matthias-eisen thankx for your answer. It worked fine. In Jinja2, `int(some_string)` does not work. I used:

```
some_string | int
```

So for my question, it should be:

```
{{ '{0:,}'.format(video_item.statistics.viewCount | int) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The API passes viewCount as a string (see https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=statistics&id=I90H3dN2HbI&_h=2&).

Inside the Handler:

```
view_count = '{0:,}'.format(int(video_item.statistics.viewCount))
```

Inside the Template:

```
{{ view_count }}
```

Also: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I've tried that too but keep getting internal server error. "UndefinedError: 'int' is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. int() is available to templates only via filter (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters) which doesn't really help in your case. See my edited answer above.